# How to retrive binary version number from binary files

Tags: c, eclipse, binary, version

I am using Eclipse IDE for developing the c programs. Through terminal I can see  the file info using **file filename** .But I need to print only the version number of a binary file through the same  code.I think the eclipse IDE keeps the build and debugging versions .How to retrive binary version number from binary files ?.

Thanks .

Comment: what is the version number of a binary file?  You mean what build number an executable is?  I don't think that's an intrinsic part of the c language or any sort of eclipse addition.  Do you have any references to this concept existing?

Comment: Can you please add more detail or give some examples? Right now your question makes no sense.

Comment: ya i mean the build number of an executable

Comment: There's no such thing as a build number in an executable binary that is present in all platforms.  What system are you building this on?  I think windows binaries often have this information present, but as far as I know, Linux executable binaries do not.

Comment: but i tried  "file filename" command from terminal it shows **sample: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped**

Comment: You mean the Eclipse equivalent of [Visual Studio's VERSIONINFO resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: I am using ubuntu,when i try **file filename** it shows a info that i mentioned in my previous comment. **Sample**  is my executable binary file and and my source code is **sample.c** i want to print the version number of the **sample** through my source code

Comment: I can't tell exactly what "version 1" refers to, but it's something to do with the format the binary is built as, not anything to do with your program or a build number.   For example, rebuild your program and see if it changes -- it won't.  It will still say version 1.

Comment: I don't think it would be easy/feasible. But for the time being you can add a `macro for version information` and add a **command line** to print the version.

Answer (score 0):

The "file" utility is a non-trivial implementation, ie., no straight-forward system calls for getting all those information.  You have two options:

1. Get the source code of "file" utility ([here](ftp://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/lfs/lfs-packages/6.3/file-4.21.tar.gz)) and manipulate it
   for your goal
2. Easier: use `popen()`, run file command, retrieve the
   output and parse it to get the information you want. The command `file <filename> | cut -d"," -f3` should directly give you the version of the executable.
   An example of using `popen()` [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/popen.html)

Hope this helps.